# Angular List item animation with custom component

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am new with angular and angular animation and I want to understand something.

I've created an animation on a list of item (on enter / on leave).
For each item, I use a custom component.
And to make the animation working, I have to wrap the component inside a div.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-question-with-component?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html

Is it a limitation ? Or can I do something to make the animation working with the "main" div of the custom component ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `display: block` to your box component host element, you can do that in css like:

```
:host {
  display: block
}
```

Here is changed example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-question-with-component-itkbjp?file=src/app/box.component.css).

Hope that helps.

Comment: By the way, thanks for providing examples in stackblitz, it's pretty handy!